# How to get the results (standard output) of a TCL exec command?

Tags: exec, tcl

Say I have a TCL script like this:

```
exec ls -l
```

Now this will print out the content of current directory. I need to take that output as a string and parse it. How I can do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`exec` returns the output so simply set a variable to it:

```
set result [exec ls -l]
```

You may want to wrap this in a `catch` however:

```
if {[catch {exec ls -l} result] == 0} { 
    # ...
} else { 
    # ... (error)
}
```

Comment: Yes, may my problem is another one. I actually call the following: `set cvsPath "C:/Program Files (x86)/cvsnt/cvs.exe"; exec $::cvsPath -n upd; puts "DONE"`, and right after `exec`ing there is no message "DONE". It seams it exits, but why?

Comment: And how can I prevent exiting?

Comment: Something is wrong with `cvs upd` command. For example `cvs log filename` works correctly.

Comment: Try putting the exec call in a try in case the csv command returns an error. try {exec $::cvsPath -n upd};

Comment: I use TCL8.4. There is no `try` there, sorry.

Comment: Catch it instead then, and see what happens. But isn't the problem, then, that the call _isn't_ exiting?

Comment: Also, *specifically for ls* you'd probably want to avoid running a subprocess for that sort of thing. All the information that it displays is available directly in Tcl via `glob` and `file stat`…